# in oop php what does using an arrow operator -> after a method do?

Tags: php, oop

Example:

```
$this->getResponse()
     ->appendBody('Hello' . $name)
```

In the previous example, I understand the use of the first arrow operator, but not the second, since I don't know whether what the second one does is similar to passing arguments to the function, in which case I wonder why it doesn't go inside the parenthesis.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe that second operator just calls `appendBody()` on the object *returned* by `$this->getResponse()`.

In other words, it's a shortcut for this:

```
$x = $this->getResponse();
$x->appendBody('Hello' . $name);
```

Comment: Thank you. I see it is a nice way to reduce code and improve readability... nice examples in the wikipedia link. Nice.

Answer (score 4):

The same as a `.` in other OOP languages: You're chaining commands together.

You call `$this->getResponse()` which returns an object, then on that object you're calling `appendBody()`.  it'd be the same as this:

```
$response = $this->getResponse();
$response->appendBody('Hello'.$name);
```

Ironically, I was just thinking about/playing with this about 10 minutes ago.

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks, I was wondering why, then realized I had some seriously messed up typos, which I subsequently fixed